# Unable to Deserialize Using JsonParser in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jetty, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to use `org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer` to perform custom deserialization.

My primary goal is to be able to hook into Jetty's JSON processing structure and use Jackson instead of the default JettyJSON.

So right now, I'm testing to see if this works.

I have a test that attempts to read a simple JSON string and convert it into a Presence object.

```
public void testBasicJson() throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException,
        IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonObjectDeserializer jod = new JsonObjectDeserializer();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("JsonObjectDeserializer",
        new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
    module.addDeserializer(JsonObject.class, jod);
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    //formatted for easy reading
    String jsonSimple = "{
        \"userEmail\":\"user1@lab.com\",
        \"type\":\"presence\",
        \"domain\":\"lab.com\"
    }";
    JsonObject pres = mapper.readValue(jsonSimple, JsonObject.class);
    System.out.println(pres.toString());
}
```

The Presence class is:

```
public class Presence extends JsonObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    protected String userEmail;
    protected String domain;
    protected String type;

    public Presence() {
    }

    //necessary GETTERs and SETTERs are created for userEmail, domain and type

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("\tuser: ");
        sb.append(userEmail);
        sb.append(" - ");
        sb.append(domain);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The parent class is:

```
import org.cometd.server.ServerMessageImpl;

public abstract class JsonObject extends ServerMessageImpl {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
}
```

The custom deserializer is:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonToken;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

public class JsonObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<JsonObject> {
    public JsonObjectDeserializer() {
        super(JsonObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        //so I'm at a loss at this point
        //if (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        //    throw new IOException("Invalid");
        //}
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is the part on the deserializer. Trying to read the tokens using JsonParser does not work as it always returns null.

I strongly believe I'm very close to the solution and am only missing one thing in the deserializer. I just need some guidance to get to the end goal.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Glad that you managed to figure it out! One question however -- class looks like a POJO, and `ObjectMapper.readValue(...)` should be able to read it right away. So I am curious as to why custom deserializer was needed? Or is it just to learn how to do it, for cases where it is needed? (which I'm sure exist)

Comment: @StaxMan yes, you're right that the `readValue()` method should work right away. What I needed it to do was to be able to return different class objects (of different parentage) based on the presence/absence of certain fields in the JSON string. It was my attempt at overriding the default JSON reading behaviour in Jetty. I now realised that this is not the right way of doing it. But at least I got to learn a bit more about Jackson! :)

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so after days of exploring and mere hours after posting my question, I've got the answer to my own question.

It was a problem of advancing the JsonParser correctly.

The contents of the method should be:

```
public JsonObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (jp.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        throw new IOException("invalid start marker");
    }
    Presence p = new Presence();
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String fieldname = jp.getCurrentName();
        jp.nextToken();  //move to next token in string
        if ("userEmail".equals(fieldname)) {
            p.setUserEmail(jp.getText());
        } else if ("domain".equals(fieldname)) {
            p.setDomain(jp.getText());
        } else if ("type".equals(fieldname)) {
            p.setType(jp.getText());
        }
    }
    jp.close();
    return p;
}
```

It took a clearer reading of http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_132.html and the Javadocs of Jackson to determine the right way of doing it.